# laravel update function is not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I want to save an image to the database

```
$img_data = file_get_contents(Input::file('imgInp'));
        $base64 = base64_encode($img_data);
        $admin = Admin::find(25);
        $admin->picture = $base64;
        $admin->update();
        echo $base64;
```

the `->update()` function seems to not doing anything to my database because the picture field is always `NULL` though the `$base64` has data. the column type in mysql database is `longblob` and I already tried to do `->save()` but still nothing is being saved to the database. help please

Comment: Any errors/exceptions ?

Comment: @André I already stated in the question that I have tried `->save()` but nothing is being saved to my database

Comment: You should not store any image as base64 in your database. Just save the img to your assets folder and store the path to the img.

Comment: @CarlosGoce I would prefer to save the image itself.

Comment: @CarlosGoce Okay that sounds a good solution, do you know how to do that in laravel?

Comment: If it's a `longblob`, you should probably not base64-encode the data. Try giving it the raw data.

Comment: @André there is no `raw` datatype

Comment: I mean just give it the `$img_data`.

Comment: @André still nothing is being saved, I tried with `->update` and with `->save()`

Comment: Maybe dump the sql query after to see what's actually happening? Edit -- the second half of my comment was wrong.

Comment: @Chelsea thanks but now I am following another approach, which is saving the image to a local file and then saving its path to the database, if that doesn't work, I will try your solution. Bty I support Chelsea over Liverbool just because I hate that dog Suarez :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is uploaded on a temporary folder so:

```
#Get the path to the uploaded img
$filePath = Input::file('imgInp')->getRealPath();
$fileName = Input::file('imgInp')->getClientOriginalName();
$extension = Input::file('imgInp')->getClientOriginalExtension();

#Lets add the extension to the file name
$fileNameWithExtension = $fileName . '.' . $extension;

#Create the folder img/uploaded on your public folder!
$destination = public_path('img/uploaded/' . $fileNameWithExtension);

#Copy the img to your desired destination
#copy ( $filePath, $destination );

#Instead of the copy function you can use this laravel function
Input::file('imgInp')->move($destination);

#Save on database the path to your img

$admin = Admin::find(25);
$admin->picture = $destination;
$admin->update();
```

I hope it works. Didn't tried it

Then if you want to show your image just do the following:

```
$admin = Admin::find(25);

#Pass the variable to your view and them, if you use blade templating system:
<img src="{{asset($admin->picture)}}">

#If you are not using blade do it this way
<img src="<?php echo asset($admin->picture); ?>">
```

Comment: where should my `destination folder` be? in the view? in the `app` in the `root`?

Comment: It depends. If the images are not private you can save them on the public folder, otherwise, save them on the storage folder. You can use the built in functions public_path('desired/destination/inside/public/folder') or storage_path('desired/destination/inside/storage/folder').

Comment: could you update your answer please with the needful code to copy to a public folder?

Comment: I updated the answer. I suggest you to check the Laravel Helper functions http://laravel.com/docs/helpers

Comment: thanks for the update, everything is working fine. except the extension of the file. the file is saved without extension. I copied you code and just change the $filename to `admin_20` +1 to you and accepted answer

Comment: I found it `$fileExtension = pathinfo(Input::file('imgInp')->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` appreciate your help a lot

Comment: I updated my answer with a better way to move the file to your public folder with a laravel function and also added the extension to the filename. I'm glad to help you

Comment: Thanks for the update, last thing please , when I want to send the image back to the view. I should encode it in base64 right?